# Nextjs13: best practice for page wide (not global) state management

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a hard time figuring out the best practices for page wide state management in Nextjs13.
Let's say I have the following page structure:
app
/dashboard
layout.tsx
page.tsx
Card.tsx
CreateForm.tsx
I want to open a form to edit an item with a click on a button inside a card component and prefill the form with the value of the selected item.

page.tsx (simplified)

```
function Page() {
    items = [item1, item2, item3] # fetch items skipped for simplicity
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    const [item, setItem] = useState(null)
    
    return (
        <div>
            {items && items.map(item -> (
                <Card item={item} setOpen={setOpen}/>
            )}
        {open && <CreateForm item={item}>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This code doesn't work since I can't define a state in page.tsx since it's a server side component.
An alternative approach would be to use the layout.tsx, turn it into a client side component and store the state there.
layout.tsx (simplified)

```
function Layout() {
    items = [item1, item2, item3] # fetch items skipped for simplicity
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    const [item, setItem] = useState(null)
    
    return (
        <div>
        {open && <CreateForm item={item}>}
        {children setOpen={setOpen} setItem={setItem}}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This also doesn't work since I can't pass props to children of a component.

A solution which works is to create a new wrapper client side component which manages the state.

```
function Page() {
    return (
        <div>
            <WrapperComp />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This feels extremely ugly & hacky.

Is there a better solution for page wide state management?